# Strange wifi issue (incorrectly maxed-out signal strength), Ubuntu 14.04, Macbook Pro Late 2013

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, macbook

OK, so currently I'm having some issues with my wifi -- it sporatically stops working and reports my wifi strength is 100% (-3dBm+, which is obviously incorrect). It worked just fine back in 13.10.

I actually had the same issue when 14.04 was in Beta, and I had to go back to 13.10 to get rid of that issue. I'm guessing it's a driver fault, so I did all the work with `b43-fwcutter`, `firmware-b43-installer` and such. `wicd` did not help. I'm using `NetworkManager`.

Here are some maybe relavent diagnosic output, when the wifi works:

```
# iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"minWIFI"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: A0:F3:C1:8B:D7:6A   
      Bit Rate=104 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

$ lscpi -nn | grep 0280

    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
```

When the wifi doesn't work:

```
# iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"minWIFI"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: A0:F3:C1:8B:D7:6A   
      Bit Rate=72 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=16 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to Broadcom proprietary drivers from additional software. Do not use `wl`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the **BCM4331** too on a **Macmini6,1** and I followed this tutorial (https://nick.groenen.me/posts/2013/11/09/fixing-the-broadcom-bcm4331-wireless-drivers-on-ubuntu-1310/) and it worked perfectly for me.

Before you try the tutorial make sure you have a network connection apart from wifi and clean your installations of the driver running:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl*
sudo apt-get purge b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43-lpphy-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

The link for the .deb file on the tutorial is broken but you can find a good link at: 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It is a good practice (and one encouraged here) to provide at least a brief description of what is involved in the provided link and the giving the link for reference/attribution purposes. This way if the link becomes unavailable for some reason your answer will remain helpful. Please edit your answer to make it so.